# Will these plugins work with wp multisite?

Tags: plugins, multisite

I just created my first network of sites with wordpress and I was installing plugins, I installed these:

> Platinium SEO Pack (http://techblissonline.com/platinum-seo-pack/)
>
> TubePress (http://www.tubepress.net)
>
> Contact Form 7 (http://contactform7.com/)
>
> Social Bookmarks (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-bookmarks/)
>
> Strictly Auto Tags (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/strictly-autotags/)
>
> SEO Smart Links (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-automatic-links/)
>
> SEO Friendly Image (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/seo-image/)
>
> Google XML Sitemaps (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/)

I "network activated" all the plugins and then I went to one of the sites dashboards, and I saw a msg from Google XML Sitemaps saying that the plugin doesn't work on multisite. Now my problem is that I don't know if the other plugins will work.

Will I have to test each feature of all the plugins or is there an easier way to know if they work on multisite?

Comment: i am seriously doubtful about the free version of tubepress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-xml-sitemaps-with-multisite-support/) for google sitemap.

For others do not network activate those plugins. Goto individual site and activate it manually.

Comment: Have you tried this one http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bwp-google-xml-sitemaps/ ? The one you show me hasn't been updated in more than one year, this one I found looks it has been updated last month.

Comment: I think that plugin is a good one. Besides its wp 3.2.1 compatible. So go for it

Comment: The plugin the link points to is gone, the BWP plugin doesn’t run here.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Contact Form 7 hit network activate and then went to an individual site, 'contact' showed up on the dashboard but when I clicked on it it said 'no item found' although the title at top of page said 'Contact Form 7' I discovered what you need to do is hit the 'Add new' button next to it and that will activate it, hope this helps!

Comment: Just a note on above you will need to hit the save button located in top box 'Untitled' in order to get the code that you will need to copy and paste into your contact page